# Delete on placement new

Tags: c++

I am aware that calling delete on a variable created using placement new and then accessing that block of memory has undefined behaviour.

```
int* x = new int[2];
char* ch = new(x) char();
*ch = 't';
delete ch;
```

But if the block of memory, instead of heap is allocated on stack and then we call delete on that variable and then access the memory, I get an exception that the **block type is invalid**.

```
int x[2];
char* ch = new(x) char();
*ch = 't';
delete ch;
```

So the list of questions is:

- Is the exception due to call of delete on a stack?
- Is it fine to use placement new on memory block on stack?
- If yes then how shall I delete the character pointer.
- Is it possible to assign multiple variables on a single block of
  memory using placement new?

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is the exception due to call of delete on a stack?

Yes. Though to clarify a little, this is not a C++ exception. It is an error that is detected by runtime. If runtime is not that smart, you could as well run into undefined behavior.

> Is it fine to use placement new on memory block on stack?

Yes. You might also take a look at [`alloca()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) and [Variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA) - those are another two mechanisms of allocating memory on stack. Note that VLA is part of C99 and not C++11 (and earlier) standards, but is supported by most production-grade compilers as an extension (it might appear in C++14).

> If yes then how shall I delete the character pointer.

You should not. When you use a placement new, you do not call `delete`, you simply invoke a destructor. For any given object `o` of type `T` you need to call `o->~T();` instead of `delete o;`. If you must, however, deal with the code that calls `delete` or `delete []` on such an object, you might need to overload operators `delete` and `delete[]` and make those operators do nothing (destructor is already ran at that point).

> Is it possible to assign multiple variables on a single block of memory using placement new?

Yes. However, you need to take extra care to make sure you meet [alignment requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Comment: A great answer. but just 1 clarification. while using placement new on a stack, is the memory allocated starting from the beginning and then moving forward or it randomly allocates memory in the given block. seems like the first option is correct. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Saksham: Placement new does not allocated any memory at all. It uses the memory specified as an argument. As for how memory is allocated on stack — it depends on the architecture, it could be growing inwards or outwards. However, any single object on stack would have its base address lower, so if you want to place multiple objects with `placement new[]`, allocate memory for them at once.

Comment: My bad for incorrect language for "memory allocated". it should have been "memory used"

Comment: _make those operators do nothing (destructor is already ran at that point)_ Post this, the deallocation of the memory earlier used by the now deleted object is also the responsibility of the caller. So calling `delete` on a placement-new constructor object is almost always wrong, since she forgot to deallocate the memory thinking `delete` did so. Instead calling the destructor manually _and_ deallocating is the way to go.